# WPF GridControl embedded in Tabcontrol get tabitem name to set columnname in grid

Tags: wpf

I am using DevExpress for WPF, following the MVVM pattern. In the view I have a tabcontrol which is populated dynamically and a devexpress gridcontrol which is populated dynamically as well. What I need to do is to change the gridcontrols column name which is partially based on the tabitem header. For Example if the tab item header is "tabitem1HeaderName" then I would like the grid column Name to be "tabitem1HeaderName Grid Column 1". To be clear I will take the tab item header and use it as the column name. I played with a sample which does this in tabs that are already created as so:

```
  <StackPanel>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="2015-01" Name="Tab2">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, StringFormat='Number Format: {0}' }" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="world" Name="Tab3">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, StringFormat='Number Format: {0}' }" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

I wanted to know how do I mimic this functionality in a tabcontrol and grid which is populated at run time

```
<TabControl  Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" Height="Auto" Background="Transparent" x:Name="Tabs" >
                    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="725" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1600" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                                <dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" >
                                    <dxgcore:GridControl.Columns>
                                        <!--<dxg:GridColumn Name="Month1" FieldName="Month01" Header="01" Visible="True" AllowEditing="False" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center">-->
                                        <dxg:GridColumn Name="Month1" FieldName="Month01" Header="{Binding SelectedItem.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Visible="True" AllowEditing="False" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Center" >
                                            <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                                                <dxe:TextEditSettings HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
                                            </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                                        </dxg:GridColumn>

                                    </dxgcore:GridControl.Columns>
                                    <dxgcore:GridControl.View>
                                        <dxgcore:TableView x:Name="View" 
                                       AllowEditing="False" 
                                       AllowBestFit="True" 
                                       AllowMoving="True" 
                                       AllowColumnFiltering="True"
                                       IsColumnMenuEnabled="True"
                                       ShowGroupPanel="False"
                                       ShowAutoFilterRow="True"
                                       AutoWidth="False" 
                                       NavigationStyle="Cell"
                                       VerticalScrollbarVisibility="Visible"
                                       HorizontalScrollbarVisibility="Visible"

                                        </dxgcore:TableView>
                                    </dxgcore:GridControl.View>
                                </dxg:GridControl>

                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                </TabControl>
```

Comment: As an opinion, combination of AttachedProperty+IMultiValueConverter could work. Attached property to set Name(because it is not dependency, you can not bind to it), IMultiValueConverter to format proper name.

Comment: got an example how to use those

Comment: I will try to write one when have enough time